# Import new custom less files after grunt configuration

Tags: magento2.2, less-css, grunt

I am using grunt tool for magento server-side less preprocessing.

I have created **_extend.less** file following directory structure for my custom less compilation

> app\design\frontend\Vendorname\themename\web\css\source\ _extend.less

After all necessary configurations of grunt I managed to compile my own less files with the grunt command

```
grunt less:themename
```

Now everything works perfectly except when I am trying to add new .less file into _extend.less through @import directive grunt doesn't publish it's symlinks to

> pub\static\frontend\Vendorname\themename\en_US\css

For example after I import **_custom_button.less** in **_extend.less** with

```
@import '_custom_button.less';
```

Now everytime I add new files with @import I have to run the commands.

```
grunt clean:themename
grunt exec:themename
```

So this workflow is conflicting when working with developers as it cleans everything in **pub\static\frontend\Magento\themename\en_US**
directory.So that is the problem.I don't want to run clean command again.

Can I do anything for that?

Comment: No need to use clean and exec command every-time, have you tried grunt watch?

Comment: Grunt watch is working actually.The problem is that in default styles-l.less file we import _extend.less later through //@magento_import directive and that's why _module.less can not get our own _extend.less file variable because it gets _module.less file from each and every module.

Comment: See blank theme styles-l.less file in which you will find //@magento_import 'source/_extend.less'; at last.

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code for add your own less file:

**You can create new less file for your theme**

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/shop1/web/css/source/_custom_button.less

**Override below file in your theme**

> /vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/source/_sources.less

**Import your less file in source.less**

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/css/source/_sources.less

Like this `@import '_custom_button.less';`

Comment: Hello hweb87, thanks for your answer but this is not what I am looking for.Actually problem is that every time I import new less fie in web directory, I had to relaunch grunt clean and grunt exec command otherwise all idea of combining all files in pub folder (which is recommanded way) with grunt will not work.

Comment: @ShashankBhatt for above solution you no need to run every time grunt clean and grunt exec command. just run grunt watch. please try once above way.

Comment: After confirming with deveopers I came to know that even I can rerun grunt clean command and they don't mind with it as they no longer have to do anything in pub/static folder until I have not put my files in app directory. So after static content deploy I can regain all files.

Comment: As per your solution, it doesn't work because symlink of newly added file to **app/design** will not published to **pub/static/frontend/magento/theme/web/cdd/source/** path automatically. Grunt will always look for file in this directory and not in app directory.To publish symlink we must run exec command.